# Javamail and Gmail get message

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a gmail account from my University,

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/181692?hl=en

The account is managed by `student.university.com`

So if I try this snipped:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        try {
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("mail.gmail.com", "username", "password");


            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
            Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
            for (Address address : in) {
                System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
            }
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
            BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
            System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
            System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
            System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());
        } catch (Exception mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But it does not work, if I try to change this:

```
    store.connect("student.university.com", "username", "pass");
```

still does not work... where am I wrong?

Edit: After 2 min I have this error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection timed out;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out;
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:670)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at RetriveMail.main(RetriveMail.java:17)
```

if i try with Debug i have:

```
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "imap.gmail.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 151.40.212.208 p48if11656880wer.170
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
A0 OK Thats all she wrote! p48if11656880wer.170
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=imap.gmail.com, user=username@student.university.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
```

Comment: It does not work **how**? People, is it really that hard to imagine that things may fail in multiple ways?

Comment: i haven't any response..

Comment: if i try this snipped with another account, but managed by Google direct works..

Comment: @FelasDroid: Define "it does not work."  What is the error?  When you debug this, in what way does it fail?

Comment: i have edited the post with error

Comment: This looks like your IMAP port is protected by a firewall.

Comment: i can get message in this case? or not?

Comment: @FelasDroid : Try store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "username", "password");

Comment: The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) has debugging tips.  Try them and post the results.

Comment: i have this result:  DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "imap.student.university.com", port 993, isSSL true

Comment: if i try with: imap.gmail.com i have:
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
A0 OK Thats all she wrote! p48if11656880wer.170
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=imap.gmail.com, user=username@student.university.com, password=non-null
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATIONFAILED

Comment: i edited the my question